# Combine 2 Azure SQL tables into 1 index in Azure Cognitive Search

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services

I'm following [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/tutorial-multiple-data-sources) on how to combine 2 different data sources into 1 index and the result is exactly what i want:
Indexed Hotels from one data source each with an array (or list) of Room details from another data source.

In my case, both my datasources come from one Azure SQL database which doesn't use partition keys:

```
        DataSource hotelSource = DataSource.AzureSql(
            name: "hotels-sql",
            sqlConnectionString: Configuration["ConnectionStrings"],
            tableOrViewName: "hotels");
        hotelSource.DataChangeDetectionPolicy = new SqlIntegratedChangeTrackingPolicy();

        DataSource roomSource = DataSource.AzureSql(
            name: "rooms-sql",
            sqlConnectionString: Configuration["ConnectionStrings"],
            tableOrViewName: "rooms");
        roomSource.DataChangeDetectionPolicy = new SqlIntegratedChangeTrackingPolicy();
```

I set up the index like so:

```
    fields = new List<Field>
    {
        Field.New("Id", DataType.String, isKey: true),
        Field.New("Name", DataType.String, isSearchable: true, isRetrievable: false, analyzerName: AnalyzerName.StandardLucene),
        Field.New("Description", DataType.String, isSearchable: true, isRetrievable: false, analyzerName: AnalyzerName.StandardLucene),
        Field.New("Category", DataType.String, isRetrievable: false, isFilterable: true),
        new Field("Rooms", DataType.Collection(DataType.Complex), new List<Field>
        {
            Field.New("Name", DataType.String, isRetrievable: false, isSearchable: true, analyzerName: AnalyzerName.StandardLucene),
            Field.New("Description", DataType.String, isRetrievable: false, isSearchable: true, analyzerName: AnalyzerName.StandardLucene),
            Field.New("Category", DataType.String, isRetrievable: false, isFilterable: true)
        })
    };

    var definition = new Index()
    {
        Name = indexName,
        Fields = fields,
        ScoringProfiles = new List<ScoringProfile>
        {
            new ScoringProfile("main", new TextWeights(new Dictionary<string, double>
            {
                {"Name", 1},
                {"Description", 0.8},
                {"Rooms/Name", 0.4},
                {"Rooms/Description", 0.3}
            }))
        },
        DefaultScoringProfile = "main"
    };

    Index index = searchService.Indexes.Create(definition);
```

I set up the mappings like so:

```
Indexer hotelIndexer = new Indexer(
                name: "hotels-indexer",
                dataSourceName: hotelSource.Name,
                targetIndexName: index.Name,
                schedule: new IndexingSchedule(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)));

List<FieldMapping> map = new List<FieldMapping> {
                new FieldMapping("HotelId", "Id")
            };

Indexer roomIndexer = new Indexer(
                name: "rooms-indexer",
                dataSourceName: roomSource.Name,
                targetIndexName: index.Name,
                fieldMappings: map,
                schedule: new IndexingSchedule(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)));
```

The Rooms table contains a column 'HotelId' which points to the Id of the Hotel it belongs to.

The result should be that the Rooms list in the Hotels index is filled with Rooms by the roomIndexer however the actual result is that the Rooms are indexed alongside the Hotels as if they were Hotels themselves. The Rooms list remains empty.

I hope I provided enough information with this.

Comment: Instead of going with two data sources and two indexers approach, wouldn’t it be better to create a view in the database that populate your index by creating an indexer/data source using that view? Just a thought.

Comment: Probably not the issue, but heads up that you've got a typo in here: `Roooms/Name` in your scoring profile.

Comment: @GauravMantri Yes I've tried this approach but I thought this approach was cleaner. maybe a database view really is the best option. But wouldn't a view make the update tracking feature useless since the view only updates when the 'create view script' is run? (correct me if I'm wrong please)

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy Not the issue indeed but thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Search does not support appending to a collection field (Rooms in the Hotels index) - it seems that you've modeled your data expecting that it does.

Instead, you could try flattening all rooms in a hotel into a single field (probably in stringified JSON representation that Azure Search can consume).